# Kripke structure, modal logic

Tags: logic, modal-logic

I would appreciate help with how to interpret a Kripke model.

I want to determine in which of the world, , of s_1-s_6, the negation to p exists ($\neg p$) but do not know how to think about an empty world or one that contains both p and q, which in this case apply to the worlds s_4 and s_6. Is it true for these two that they contain $\neg p$?

If I am to guess, the empty world should contain the negation of p as p does not exist in the world at all, but in the world that contains both p and q, I am even more divided. Can really the negation to p exist in a world if both p and non-p exist in the world?

[image]

Comment: I am not sure that this is the best site for this question, you might try asking it at https://cs.stackexchange.com instead. (if you do, remember to delete it here as well).

Comment: @RBarryYoung Oh, ok. Thank you!